# Make sum of elements when case is lower than specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The problem is when the `paymentDate` is lower than 2005, it must make sum of all element in `champs1` + `champs2` with payment lower than 2005.

But in this code, it makes sum of all `champs1 + champs2` even if the payment is higher than 2005 and that is not what i am looking for.

Any help please .

```
select 
    case 
       when dateEntry < 2011 and PaymentDate < 2005 
          then ISNULL(Champs1, 0) + ISNULL(Champs2, 0) - ISNULL(Champs3, 0)
          else 0
    end
```

My table sample:

```
SELECT * INTO #Paiment FROM ( VALUES (2013, 90, 70, 60), 
(2011, 20, 30, 40), (2009, 50, 0, 60), (2008, 60, 16, 60), (2007, 0, 36, 20), 
(2006, 30, 25, 63), (2017, 10, 70, 40), (2019, 20, 30, 32), (2030, 50, 0, 63), 
(2020, 60, 16, 22), (2018, 0, 36, 33), (2005, 30, 25, 17)
) as t(PaimentDate, Champs1, Champs2, Champs3)
```

Comment: Provide some sample of data, please.

Comment: INSERT INTO Paiment (PaimentDate, Champs1, Champs2, Champs3)
VALUES (2013, 90, 70, 60), (2011, 20, 30, 40), (2009, 50, 0, 60), 
       (2008, 60, 16, 60), (2007, 0, 36, 20), (2006, 30, 25, 63),
       (2017, 10, 70, 40), (2019, 20, 30, 32), (2030, 50, 0, 63), 
       (2020, 60, 16, 22), (2018, 0, 36, 33), (2005, 30, 25, 17) , this is my table

Comment: In sample you provided there is no data for 2004 and earlier

Comment: To be honest, i do not quite understand what are you expecting from this sample data. Could you please show the target result set?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM demo where date <= '2016-01-12';
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am talking with to sum two colums when the date is lower than a specific date

Comment: means you are talking about from_date to to_date ?

Comment: No i mean to sum two columns when the date is lower for example 2011 , i do not want to have the date higher than 2011 ,

Answer (score 0):

There are a few dependencies between your description of what you want and your sample data. This means I need to guess a little and make some assumptions.

Let's assume you wanted the SUM of champs1 + champs2 when PaimentDate < 2005 and a 0 for PaimentDate's 2005+. For that you could do this:

```
-- sample data
SELECT * INTO #Paiment 
FROM (VALUES (2003, 90, 70, 60), (2002, 20, 30, 40), (2002, 150, 0, 65), 
      (2008, 60, 16, 60), (2007, 0, 36, 20),(2004, 30, 25, 17))
  as t(PaimentDate, Champs1, Champs2, Champs3);

-- solution
SELECT
  PaimentDate, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN PaimentDate < 2005 THEN ISNULL(Champs1,0) + ISNULL(Champs2,0) ELSE 0 END)
    AS x
FROM #Paiment
GROUP BY PaimentDate;
```

Note that, in the sample data here, I added some pre-2005 dates.

Comment: First I seek a minimum year in another table then from this year, I compare if the year is less than in 2005 and that same year is less on the date of payment in table paiement so ,I want to make the sum  (champs1 + champs3 ) - (champ4) else if the minimum year is higher year to 2005, I want to make the sum of the champs1 where dateofEntry is less than years minimum +  the sum of the champs2 where  years minimum is less than 2005 - the sum of the champs1 where dateofEntry is less than years minimum